# How to use linq contains method on IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use the contains method from Linq on a object that implements IEnumerable, but not able to figure it out

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents a collection of form fields.
    [DefaultMember("Item")]
    public class FormFieldList : IEnumerable
    {

        public FormField this[string name] { get; }

        public FormField this[int index] { get; }

        public int Count { get; }

        public FormField Owner { get; }


        public int Add(FormField formField);

        public void DrawKidReferences(DocumentWriter writer);

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();

        public TextFieldList GetTextFields();

        public void Remove(FormField field);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of [`Contains<TSource>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TSource value
)
```

As you can see in order to use this method (as will as other LINQ extension methods except `Cast` and `OfType`), your class should implement generic interface `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you know the type of items which is returned by your enumerator (assume it's `FormField`), then you can cast source sequence items to that type and get `IEnumerable<FormField>`:

```
formFieldList.Cast<FormField>().Contains(someFormField)
```

Comment: @billboard use `Enumerable.Cast<T>()` and make sure that `FormField` overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods - otherwice `someFormField` will be compared by reference instead of comparing by value. Or you can use `Contains` overload with custom equality comparer as argument